# \abovedisplayskip and \belowdisplayskip : why doesn't it work?

Tags: math-mode, vertical-spacing

In the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}

\def\someText{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}

\begin{document}

\someText
\[
1+1=2
\]
\someText

\end{document}
```

why is there such space around the equation `1+1=2`? What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: You can print `\the\abovedisplayskip` to see if it has been changed and to what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in `size10.clo`, you find

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xiipt
   \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
\normalsize
```

And LaTeX executes again `\normalsize` at begin document. If you want to change the values for the skips around displays, you need to patch `\normalsize` and the other font changing commands you need. The parameters are set for `\small` and `\footnotesize`.

Comment: Thanks! What's the aim of `\abovedisplayskip` if one can't simply set its value?!!

Comment: @Colas You *do* set it. But since you want it to have different values in different situations…

Comment: Thanks. I got it.