# Change \abovedisplayskip & \belowdisplayskip

Tags: math-mode, vertical-spacing, belowdisplayskip

To change the vertical spacing above and below math displays, the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47776/13492 uses:

```
\g@addto@macro \normalsize{%
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{4pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}%
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{4pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}}
```

But this does not seem to work in the following: the spacing applied is still the default 10pt (+/-) How can it be fixed?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \g@addto@macro \normalsize{%
    \setlength\abovedisplayskip{4pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}%
    \setlength\belowdisplayskip{4pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent Since $D$ is denumerable, the set 
\[
C = \bigcup_{d \in D} \bigl(J_{d} \setminus f^{-1}(1)\bigr)
\]
is countable. Here, for each $x$,
\begin{align*}
I_{x} &= \{(x, y) : 0 \leq y < 2\},\\
J_{x} &= \{(x + y, y) : 0 \leq y < 2\},
\end{align*}
respectively.

\medskip

\noindent\begin{tabular}{ll}
\verb!\abovedisplayskip! & \the\abovedisplayskip\\
\verb!\belowdisplayskip! & \the\belowdisplayskip
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Still uses default vertical spacing]

*Related:* https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/605918/13492

Comment: Did you find `\AtBeginDocument` in the linked answers?

Comment: @egreg: Yes, I had found that in the linked answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the values in the preamble rather than at the beginning of the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\makeatletter
  \g@addto@macro \normalsize{%
    \setlength\abovedisplayskip{4pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}%
    \setlength\belowdisplayskip{4pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent Since $D$ is denumerable, the set 
\[
C = \bigcup_{d \in D} \bigl(J_{d} \setminus f^{-1}(1)\bigr)
\]
is countable. Here, for each $x$,
\begin{align*}
I_{x} &= \{(x, y) : 0 \leq y < 2\},\\
J_{x} &= \{(x + y, y) : 0 \leq y < 2\},
\end{align*}
respectively.

\medskip

\noindent\begin{tabular}{ll}
\verb!\abovedisplayskip! & \the\abovedisplayskip\\
\verb!\belowdisplayskip! & \the\belowdisplayskip
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]